# Trying to merge two sorted dynamic arrays - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, overloading

I have a template class called OrderedList which is made to take a primitive data type and order it into a list from smallest to largest. I am trying to overload the addition operator to allow two lists to be merged into one OrderedList. I want the method to return a new OrderedList object but I am getting an error
Here is my code for the OrderedList + operator method. I have not yet tested the logic in this method, so I assume there are some errors. I am just currently trying to get the + operator to merge the arrays and return a new object

```
   template<class mytype>
OrderedList<mytype>& OrderedList<mytype>::operator+ (const OrderedList<mytype>& a)
{
int size = a.size() + count;
int i=0, j=0, k=0;
OrderedList<mytype> *newList = new OrderedList<mytype>(size);

   while (i < a.size() && j < count) {
        if (a[i] <= list[j]) {
             newList[k] = a[i];
              i++;
        } else {
              newList[k] = list[j];
              j++;
        }
        k++;

  if (i < a.size()) {
        for (int p = i; p < a.size(); p++) {
              newList[k] = a[p];
              k++;
        }
  } else {
        for (int p = j; p < count; p++) {
              newList[k] = list[p];
              k++;
        }
  }
}
return newList;
}
```

Comment: You allocate a new list and then return a pointer to it. But your function type expects you to return a reference. The plus operator should return a new instance of the type. Create the instance of your class in the function add the two lists and return the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

As @ConnorHollis already pointed out in the comment, you are allocating a new `OrderedList` instance inside the `+`-operator. Apart from this not working because of different types and being dangerous because returning a reference generally indicates that the caller does not need to care about ownership, it's also very unexpected. The `+`-operator should always return a new object, that is returned copy constructed.

Answer (score 1):

Your method definition looks like this.

```
OrderedList<mytype>& OrderedList<mytype>::operator+ (const OrderedList<mytype>& a)
```

However the plus operator usually returns a new instance of the class type so it should likely be:

```
OrderedList<mytype> OrderedList<mytype>::operator+ (const OrderedList<mytype>& a)
```

Without the reference as you can see.

Now you have a pointer to a new OrderedList but you don't need to allocate it! You can just create an instance of it and return it via a copy constructor or assignment operator. So I would change the new list instantiation to look like this:

```
OrderedList<mytype> newList(size);
```

Then it will likely compile.

I decided to make you a simple demo! http://ideone.com/bFiv1W

Hopefully that explains it a little better.

Comment: Ok I under stand it a bit better now. In class we create an array list class and in our main program, the lists were declared as MyArrayList<mytype> *list = new MyArrayList<mytype>. That is how I have been declaring my ordered list objects in my main program and it hasn't been working. I tried your way of declaring new objects and it has worked. Now I just need to find an efficient way of adding the two arrays together and keeping them ordered. They keyword being, efficient.